# Updating Many To Many collection using .NET EF Core 5 TrackableEntities

Tags: many-to-many, entity-framework-core-2.1

After a few nights of trial and error, I've been unable to find a way to update a collection of custom types in a Many To Many relationship with Trackable Entities.

I have a type `Bar` that can be assigned to a collection member of `Foo` (`Foo.Bars`). In the API consumer, users select zero-to-many `Bar` from a list which means Bars may be added of removed from the `Foo.Bars` collection.

This is in an MVC setting, which is why I'm using TrackableEntities to manage updating properties. The best I've managed is to get selected `Bar` added to the collection. If a Foo that already had Bars in the `Foo.Bars` collection is posted back with no changes to the `.Bars` collection, EF produces a Foreign key violation as the same Bar is added again. Removing a Bar from the list in the frontend and posting the collection back with the new desired state of the collection does not remove the desired Bar(s) when saved. I toyed with setting the TrackingState of these `Bar` to deleted or modified but it appears to be ignored which does make sense - the Bar entity is not being updated or deleted; it's the `Foo.Bars` property that should be changed.

Has anyone worked with TrackableEntities and been able to get EF Core 5 Many-To-Many navigation properties to be managed? There's no sample of it in the TrackableEntities/TrackableEntities.Core.Sample project. Apparently TrackableEntities had M-to-M support in 2015 but I haven't been able to find anyone talking about it since.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your many-to-many is modelled like this:

```
public class Foo {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

You can call `clear()` on a tracked instance of `Foo`, and then re-add the `Bar` instances that you want assigned. I've found that avoids the constraint exception.

```
var foo = context.Foos.Include(x => x.Bars).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == someGuid);
foo.Bars.Clear();
foo.Bars.Add(bar1);
foo.Bars.Add(bar2);
...
context.Update(foo);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing... thankfully I don't need this to be performant at the moment. But it does seem like this is something TrackableEntities should be able to handle. Avoiding this hamfisted approach is the whole point of TrackableEntities.